# CSS: Two pictures showing in one column

Tags: css

Would you help me please make appear pictures in one column? It needs to be full width with no space between those images.

Thanks in advance.

**What I want it to look like**

[image]

**What I have**

[image]

**Code:**

```css
img,
.image {
  display: block;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

<section class="main">
<div class="container">
<div class="full-width">
<div class="vibe_editor clearfix">
<div class="v_module v_column col-md-12 fullwidth v_first">
<style>
<div class="v_module v_text_block about_us">
<p>
<a href="http://www.kurzon.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/homepage-o-nas.jpg?189db0">
<img class="alignnone size-big wp-image-3125" width="768" height="282" alt="o-nas1" src="http://www.kurzon.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/homepage-o-nas-768x282.jpg?189db0">
</a>
<a href="http://www.kurzon.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/2048x1536-orange-red-solid-color-background.jpg?189db0">
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="v_module v_column col-md-12 fullwidth v_first">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>

href="http://www.kurzon.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/homepage-o-nas.jpg?189db0"> <img class="alignnone size-big wp-image-3125" width="768" height="282" alt="o-nas1" src="http://www.kurzon.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/homepage-o-nas-768x282.jpg?189db0"> </a> <a href="http://www.kurzon.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/2048x1536-orange-red-solid-color-background.jpg?189db0"> </p> </div> </div> <div class="v_module v_column col-md-12 fullwidth v_first"> </div> </div> </div> </section>
```

Comment: Can you create a demo of the code perfectly as it is in your output?

Comment: May I ask where should I paste it here? I cant see a button edit or anything like that..

Comment: You can use http://codepen.io or http://jsfiddle.net and post the link here. There is a set of links to the left of your name. You can click on edit.

Comment: Done. What do you think?

Comment: There is nothing currently added buddy. Have you missed to add a http://codepen.io demo?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpYrVR?editors=110

(I copied the whole homepage... Hope thats ok.. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not output anything. Please update the code.

Comment: I dont know what did I do wrong? I just copied and pasted...

Answer (score 0):

The `p` tag has padding by default remove it?

Also remove unwanted `<style>` tag